# Looping Through WordsList Cannot Offset Data per Collection

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

A bit of a dumb question probably an easy answer!

I am trying to loop through data, I split it via delimiter and then want to offset each split part into the row, and move onto the next row / data,

Here is my code:

```
Dim undelimitedstring As String

    undelimitedstring = AlphaNumericOnly(rng.Value)

    WordsList = Split(undelimitedstring, "Q")

    result = ""
    Count = UBound(WordsList)

    For i = 1 To Count

        Dim ios As Integer
        ios = 0
        Worksheets("Calendar").Range("H" & rng.Row).Activate
        MsgBox (WordsList(i))

        For Each element In WordsList
            Dim n As Integer
            Dim o As Integer
            n = 0
            o = 1
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, n).Value = WordsList(o)
        Next element

    ios = ios + 1
    Next i
```

If someone can help that would be fab!

Comment: It almost sounds like it should be easy, but I don't know what _I split it via delimiter and then want to offset each split part into the row_ means.  In your comments on answers below you give `130091 1000091` as examples, but I don't know what the original string is or how you got to those figures - offsetting by a split I guess.  Your code is splitting by a `Q` delimiter, but those figures don't contain a `Q`.... I'm confused!  How do you define `rng`?  Is the code a sub or function? .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will do what you expect, it will get all the values in WordsList and enter each value into a new row on Column H:

```
Dim undelimitedstring As String

undelimitedstring = AlphaNumericOnly(Rng.Value)

WordsList = Split(undelimitedstring, "Q")

result = ""

For i = 1 To UBound(WordsList)
    NextFreeRow= Worksheets("Calendar").Cells(Worksheets("Calendar").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Worksheets("Calendar").Range("H" & NextFreeRow).Value = WordsList(i)
Next i
```

**UPDATE:**

The amended code below will add two values from WordList to a row in adjacent cells and then move to the next row and add the next two values, and so on:

```
Dim undelimitedstring As String

undelimitedstring = AlphaNumericOnly(Rng.Value)

WordsList = Split(undelimitedstring, "Q")

result = ""
NextFreeRow = Worksheets("Calendar").Cells(Worksheets("Calendar").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Counter = 0
For i = 1 To UBound(WordsList)
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Worksheets("Calendar").Range("H" & NextFreeRow).Value = WordsList(i)
    If Counter = 2 Then
    Worksheets("Calendar").Range("I" & NextFreeRow).Value = WordsList(i)
        NextFreeRow = NextFreeRow + 1
        Counter = 0
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Hello, with this code it is not outputting anything in Column H, Changed to, Worksheets("Calendar").Range("H" & rng.Row).Value = WordsList(i) but still only outputs in first row and doesnt go into second for second value

Comment: @AshleyDavies I've now updated my answer, I believe it should now work for you.

Comment: @Ashley Davies You should also look into how for each loops work. They automatically attribute the content of wordlist(o) to element. They do not however increment an iteration counter (you must do that by writing n=n+1 inside the loop). In your case, a for next loop is perhaps the best option.

Comment: @Xabier I have used that code, we are getting somewhere, but now it is outputting them directly down, like this, 130091
100091
91930
99115
99805

Comment: I would want it, 130091 1000091

Comment: and so on down and down, different values and amount of collections each time

Comment: Unfortunetely does still not do what i want, It is now putting the values in the same column but with the two in the same cell, I need seperate cells for each value and then to the next line

Comment: All I want, is for each value in wordlist to go in seperate cells on the right and then next row = new wordlist so same again and so on so on

Comment: @AshleyDavies I think I understood now, first value in column H, second value in Column I, then next row and the same... Please see my updated code once more...

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a guess here on what you mean by

> I split it via delimiter and then want to offset each split part into
>   the row

This code will take a string like **123 456 Q 654 321 987 Q 789 012** and split it to three rows:

- 123 456
- 654 321 987
- 789 012

**To use:**
If A1 contains **123 456 Q 654 321 987 Q 789 012** then highlight `C1:C3` and enter `=SplitString(A1)` as an array formula.

```
Public Function SplitString(Target As Range, Optional Delim As String = "Q") As Variant

    SplitString = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(Target, Delim))

End Function
```

---

If you want it as a procedure rather than a function use:

```
Sub Test()

    SplitString_2 Sheet1.Range("A1"), Sheet1.Range("D1")

End Sub

Public Sub SplitString_2(Target As Range, Destination As Range, Optional Delim As String = "Q")

    Dim vSplit As Variant
    Dim lElements As Long

    vSplit = Split(Target, Delim)
    lElements = UBound(vSplit) + 1 'Assumes LBound = 0

    Destination.Resize(lElements) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vSplit)

End Sub
```